# Selecting specific svg path based on JSON attribute in d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

Is it possible to select only one of the SVG paths created from a geoJSON file using D3? In my case the paths are areas in a map. The user can choose an area from a dropdown list. I want to use the selected value from this list to select the path with the matching attribute and color it differently. The name of the area is one of the attributes in the geoJSON file.

Can I qualify the `d3.select("path")` further by adding some kind of filter?

This is how the code looks like ...

```
d3.json(polygonFile, function(json) {
            for (var g = 0; g < json.features.length; g++) {
              if(json.features[g].properties.NAME == selectedAreaName) {
                d3.select("path") //THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO ADD THE FILTER ...
                    .transition()
                    .duration(600)
                    .style("filter", "brightness(0.7)")
              }
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend doing this whole thing in a more D3-esque way instead of iterating through `json.features`. `json.features` is *data*, so let’s use D3’s data binding approach.

```
// this would get set elsewhere
// be sure to call update() any time this chages!
let selectedAreaName = "area51";

let myData; // storing this someplace accessible from outside the d3.json callback
d3.json(polygotFile, json => {
    myData = json;
    update();
});

function update() {
    // create initial features selection based on data
    let features = d3.select("svg").selectAll("path").data(myData.features);

    // add new features to the selection using the enter selection,
    // and merge back into the original update selection
    features = features.enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", d3.geoPath())
        .merge(features);

    // this is what you're trying to do:
    // every time update() runs, it’ll apply a class
    // to paths whose name == selectedAreaName
    features.classed("selected", d => d.properties.NAME == selectedAreaName);
}
```

Comment: Your approach helped me very much to get my script working. Thanks @Noleli.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to deal with your problem:

You can use `d3.selectAll` and filter your paths according to their data/specific attributes.

```
d3.selectAll("path").filter((d) => d.uniqueId === 12345)
```

You can even use selector instead of function:

```
d3.selectAll("path").filter(".className")
```

In case there are a lot of paths you do not want to use filter because it will iterate through all the paths before returning the correct one, so you can set id attribute and use `d3.select('#yourpathid')`

Hope it helps!